# Inconsistent E-step calibration test results

Tags: creality-ender-3, calibration, underextrusion

My Ender 3 has been having intermittent under extrusion issues.  Layers of good density alternate with weak mesh.  When printing multiple objects at once, sometimes one will be almost entirely good, while the piece next to it is all meshy; so it's not even consistent within layers, or between sections of the print bed.

I've cleaned it and replaced everything from the stepper handle to the hot end.

Today I've been trying to calibrate E-steps, and they're all over the place:

- Initial tests produced from 19 to 23 mm (should be 100 mm)
- I calibrated to an average of those, and then tests ranged 105 to 115 mm
- I tried a different spool of filament; that one produced 58 and 67 mm.

What can be causing these inconsistent results?

Comment: Getting 19 to 23 when it should be 100 is not something you can "calibrate out". It's indicative of a serious (likely mechanical) failure somewhere. Put the esteps back where they started (93) and look for the problem. Your extruder tension arm is probably cracked or the spring has no tension, or the hob gear is damaged or full of plastic shavings.

Comment: Thanks.  I replaced the tension arm (no apparent damage), spring, and hob gear just before calibrating.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the hotend jammed? Can you push material through it by hand without difficulty? When you do esteps tests, can you tell if the material is slipping on the hob gear, or if the hob gear stutters or stops turning? It's possible you have electrical or logic problems causing it to lack torque or otherwise miss steps.

Comment: Uhoh.  Somebody installed the new gear wrong.  Reinstalled, estep test at 97mm, adjusted, test print in progress.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Oops.  I had replaced the tension arm, spring, and hob gear before calibrating.  Turns out I attached the gear too low, so it wasn't pushing the filament through.

Adjusted the gear, and calibration tests became consistent.  Printing nicely now.

Comment: It is appreciated that you returned to answer your own question, thanks!